# Matching multiple and optional words in single sentence using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have 2 sentences as example

```
Sentence 1 : "The word is [WORD1] , second word is [WORD2]"

Sentence 2 : "The word is [WORD1] , second word is [WORD2] , third word is [WORD3]"
```

I need a single regex that will extract the words enclosed in square brackets if any of the above sentence is given as input.

I tried the following one

```
/^.+(\[[A-Z\d]+\]).+(\[[A-Z\d]+\]).*(\[[A-Z\d]+\])?$/)
```

I got output correctly for first sentence as WORD1 WORD2
but for second sentence I am getting the output WORD2 WORD3.

What changes do I need to make ?

Comment: use lazy quantifiers `.+?` and `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy quantifiers:

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tM3iE9/1)

This regex will match any text inside brackets. `$1` will contain the text without the surrounding brackets.

And, if you need a single word, you can forbid spaces with this regex: `\[(\S+?)\]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?:.*?\[)(.*?)\](?:.*?)
```

Have a look at the DEMO.

http://regex101.com/r/iY2hO8/1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `g` modifier to enable [global matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) and capture all matches into an array:

```
my @array = $sentence =~ /(\[[A-Z\d]+\])/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = qq!The word is [WORD1] , second word is [WORD2] , third word is [WORD3]!;

while( $str =~ m/\[([^\]]+)\]/g ) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

or, if you what in an array:

```
my @words =  $str =~ m/\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two flaws in your regex:

- By using greedy matching `.*`, you risk gobbling matches
- Placement of the words is not relevant to their matching.

To simplify your goal, instead of using a regex to match the whole line, I'd recommend just matching the words while using the `/g` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).  Additionally, it's always wise to add logic to detect when no matches are found.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my @words = /\[(.*?)\]/g) {
        print "Words = @words\n";
    } else {
        warn "No words found for line $.\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
The word is [WORD1] , second word is [WORD2]
The word is [WORD1] , second word is [WORD2] , third word is [WORD3]
```

Outputs:

```
Words = WORD1 WORD2
Words = WORD1 WORD2 WORD3
```